# How do I exit edit mode in VoiceOver on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, accessibility, screen-readers, voiceover

Once I enter an editable text field and I have finished typing, what gesture do I need to use in VoiceOver to exit edit mode? I can do this by selecting the Cancel or Done button but is there a gesture to exit edit mode and move to the next control?

Comment: why not add your own gesture recognizer? something like swipe down to fire the method that exits the edit mode?

Comment: So, there is no inbuild gesture to exit edit mode using voiceover?

Comment: if you are looking at something like saying "exit edit mode" will fire a method, no.

Answer (score 0):

Either tap the done button, or swite to the left or right. If you swipe you need to make sure you swipe above the keyboard or else you will just cycle through all the available keys.

Comment: Hmm, once I am in edit mode, there really is nothing I can do (like swiping anywhere) to exit it except by double tapping done/cancel